# ALOS WORLD 3D - 3M

Tags: dem

I am confused about what DEM does the [ALOS](https://www.eorc.jaxa.jp/ALOS/en/index_e.htm) Global Digital Surface Model "ALOS World 3D - 30m" (a.k.a. [AW3D30](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/AW3D30)) represents. It says that it is DSM but when I open it, it looks like DTM.

Can you enlighten me about their differences since I am interested in the extraction slope of rooftops?

Answer (score 0):

A Digital Terrain Model represents the surface of the earth, without any vegetation or man-made structures.

A Digital Surface Model (as you alluded to) includes all features that appear on the surface - vegeations and man-made features included.

According to the AW3D30 Wiki:

> Warning: this surface model, as well as many others, including SRTM,
> has significant feature: it does not reflect a shape of a ground
> surface but reflects an envelope surface, "draping" over buildings,
> tree tops and other natural and man-made objects.

So it appears that there is an algorithm that "averages" out these surface features to try and create a homogoneous representation of the surface.

This would mean that the ALOS dataset may not be the appropriate dataset for your "roof top" slope assessment. If you can, I would try and source a finer resolution dataset, possibly raw LiDAR data.

Comment: Thank you so much